# No Encuentra el JDK en Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, java

Tengo un problema al tratar de instalar android Studio en Ubuntu 14.04. Me aparece el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Cannont start Android Studio
>   No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Ya estuve investigando y solo encontré una solución en Windows en la cual se tienen que crear variables de entorno, pero en ubuntu no encuentro nada, y se supone que ya tengo instalado el JDK.

Comment: Pero tienes instalado el JDK, en mi experiencia, al momento de instalar ubuntu genera de forma automática las rutas al JDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes configurar tu variable `JAVA_HOME` en `/etc/profile` pero preferentemente guarda `JAVA_HOME` o cualquier variable de sistema en `/etc/environment`.

Abre `/etc/environment` En nano o gedit y agrega lo siguiente:

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk"` (La ruta puede ser diferente dependiendo tu maquina)

Ahora corre el siguiente comando para cargar las variables:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Despues checa el contenido de tu variable con el siguiente comando:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Si se imprime en pantalla la ruta lo haz hecho correctamente y lo mismo aplica para las demas variables.

Referencia en ingles [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java).