# Error en compilar app en Apache Cordova - Ubuntu

Tags: android, apache, cordova, compilar

Estoy tratando de compilar un app de prueba.

```
seva@stn:~/hello$ cordova build android
```

Cuando ejecuto la orden me sale un error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/seva/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:38:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:26:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

No entiendo bien el error, tendria que darle permiso 777 a`/home/seva/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json`?

Bueno, espero me ayuden. gracias

Comment: tu usuario no tiene permiso de escritura, intentalo hacer con `>sudo cordova build android`

Comment: ¿El error ocurre con esta app en concreto o con todas las apps? Mirando online, podría ocurrir por un error al instalarse Cordova. En [esta pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812158/ionic-update-notifier-cordova-json-you-dont-have-access-to-this-file), las respuestas recomiendan cambiar los permisos (como sugieres) o reinstalar cordova.

Comment: eso es lo que no se... estoy reinstalando cordova, pero no se si el usuario tiene acceso. cual es el usuario?

Comment: Bueno, vamos por partes. Cuando quiero compilar me pasa con todas las app (son dos), cree una mas y me pasa lo mismo. Reinstales Cordova e hice un add a platform de android y me de este mensaje aunque lo agrega: (node:3548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`.

Comment: Entonce trato de compilar otra vez, con sudo y sin sudo y no logro compilar

Comment: agregastes la plataforma a compilar? el comando debe ser algo como `cordova platform add android`

Comment: si, agrege la plataforma

Comment: iintenta agregar la plataforma con sudo

Comment: Cuando reinstalaste Cordova, ¿fue con el comando que se pone en la respuesta en inglés: `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true cordova`? (parece que la parte de `--unsafe-perm=true` es lo que hace que se solucione el problema según los comentarios)

Comment: estas ejecutando dento del proyecto los comandos?

Comment: Lo hice tal cual, ahora me da otro error:

Comment: (node:4075) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually

Comment: es necesario instalar el plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist?

Comment: El error de java puede ser porque en ubuntu tengo instaladas las dos versiones, JDK 8 y 9?

Comment: te esta diciendo que no encuentra la variable de entorno `JAVA_HOME` debes agregarla a tu variable de entorno mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1801/no-encuentra-el-jdk-en-ubuntu-14-04/1803#1803

Comment: Gracias Jack, la verdad hice todo, pero creo que hay una ruta que no se cual es que lleva a JAVA_HOME. Trate nuevamente de compilar y me este error: **Android Studio project detected
(node:11402) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.**